# rails different form attributes based on category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, attributes

I have a rails app!

I'd like to create a form for a `product` model, where users can choose a product category first and then can fill the form out.

This would be easy, but I'd like to show them different attributes based on the chosen category. Something like if they choose book category, then they will have fields like `title`, `author`, `published_at`, but if they choose shoes category then they can fill out the `size`, `color` and `type` fields.

I saw afew tuts about dynamic forms, but as far as I understand it, I don't need that since the form fields will be predefined and users won't be able to add extra fields.

What is the good approach in this case? Should I create more different models like (`shoes`,`books`, etc.) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create more different models

No, I don't think that's necessary.

What you'd be *best* doing is using `ajax` to populate the `form` on `category` change. This would require some configuration, but will make it the most efficient and secure:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :products do
  put :new, on: :new #-> url.com/products/new
end

#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    if request.get?
      @product    = Product.new
      @categories = Category.all
    elsif request.put?
      @category   = params[:product][:category_id]
      @attributes = ...
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end 
  end
end

#app/views/products/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, {}, { data: { remote: true, url: new_product_path, method: :put }} %>
   <div class="attributes"></div>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/views/products/new.js.erb
$attributes = $(...); // need a way to create form elements from @attributes
$("form#new_product .attributes").html( $attributes );
```

---

Something important to note is that `Rails` `select` & `check` elements allow you to use the `data-remote` attribute to send an ajax call to your controller on change.

Not much documentation about it, playing around with the above code should get it to work.

Comment: Richard, thanks for the super quick answer. Could you elaborate it a bit more with the example I wrote (shoes, books)? I don't see some things: How  a category can be defined? (Should I do like `category_id: 1` and `category_type: "book"`?) How exactly can I add attributes to the different categories (how to save to db --> simple attributes or serialized hash)? Could you pls update your answer with a `schema.rb` ?

Comment: Well... how are you managing categories? You asked a question about changing the form, not how you should structure your backend. I can update the answer but I need to know how you want it to work -- do you have a separate `Category` model etc?

Comment: Sry, my question is not clear. It's not created yet. There will be 3-4 categories. If you try to create a `product`, then you choose a `category` with a select_helper and once you've selected it, the rest of the form gets visible based on what you've chosen. Till now it's easy. I get confused when it comes to the different attributes based on the different `categories`. So book category will have title and author attr's and shoes will have size and color. I don't know what the optimal way is to structure the models/attr's in this case. I think I can make it work, but would be a super bad code.

Comment: You're getting into the realms of metaprogramming. I've wanted similar functionality myself; if you want to create different attributes *on the fly*, you'd have to rely mostly on your code to pull it off

Comment: Do you want to go into chat about it? I've got *some* experience with it, not a huge amount

Comment: Yeah sure, would be awesome to talk about it. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103415/discussion-between-richard-peck-and-szilard-magyar).